Can the integral of a function along a curve around several singularities be determined by finding a single residue?
Someone told me that if you want to calculate the integral of a function $f$ along a curve $C$ around all of it's singularities, then the following strangely looking formula can be used. $$\int_C f(z)dz = 2 \pi i×Res_{z=0} \left(\frac {1}{z^2}×f\left(\frac {1}{z}\right)\right)$$ Is this a well known result? If so, what is it called? What kind of argument could be used to prove something like that? Isn’t it surprising that it's enough to find a single residue in a situation where several singularities are involved?

Your formula is wrong. The correct formula is given by Cauchy's Residue Theorem, which you can find in any book on complex analysis (eg. Ahlfors, or Conway). If only one of the singularities is a pole, and the other singularities are removable singularities, then the integral can be computed by knowledge of this just one residue (corresponding to the pole) (using Cauchy's residue theorem).  After defining the function $f(z)$ appropriately at the removable singularities.

I assumed you meant finding the integral of an analytic function along a simple closed curve such that the function is analytic in the domain bounded by the curve except for finitely many isolated singularities -- this is the assumption in Cauchy's residue theorem.

Yes, and someone said that the formula I've mentioned can be used in a special case. It's not the formula from the residue theorem.

I am not aware of this formula you have mentioned above, and as to whether it can be used in a special case.  I hope my answer was helpful.

The term on the right is the  Residue at infinity
It arises from the change of variables $w=1/z$.

Ok. How can there be a residue at infinity, which is not even a point, and what happens with all the other residues? Why don't they matter anymore?
